# why does my label doesn't show my timer time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

when I tried to do a little timer without the timer my code is running well but my label doesn't show the time as it runs down what is wrong?

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBOutlet weak var out4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var out1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var out2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var out3: UILabel!

    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
        if out2.text != ""{
            var counterheure:Int = 23;
            var counterminute:Int = 60;
            var countersec:Int = 60;
            var counter:Int;
            counter = Int(out2.text!)!;
            counter = counter - 1;


            while counter != 0 {


                out3.text = "Days : \(counter); Hours : \(counterheure); Minutes : \(counterminute); Seconds : \(countersec); left before your next exam";
                countersec = countersec - 1;
                sleep(1);
                if countersec == 0{
                    counterminute = counterminute - 1;
                    countersec = 60;
                    if counterminute == 0{
                        counterheure = counterheure - 1;
                        counterminute = 60;
                        if counterheure == 0{
                            counter = counter - 1;
                            counterheure = 24;
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you may not be on one thread. You should use a DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: ). It could solve your issue

Comment: Basically your out3.text is empty right ?

Comment: Oh and don't `sleep(1)`. Never ever. This is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because your loop blocks the main thread which is also responsible for updating the UI.

I suggest using a Timer:

```
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    // This is called every second
}
```